# GWTP - Inject widget in another view

Tags: view, inject, gwtp

I'm working on a project that uses GWTP and I was wondering if I can inject a view's object into another view. something like:

```java
public class BarView extends ViewWithUiHandlers<BarUiHandlers> implements BarPresenter.BarView {    
    public interface Binder extends UiBinder<HTMLPanel, BarView> {
    }

    @UiField SomeWidget someWidget;

    @Inject
    public PlayerView(Binder binder) {
        initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}

public class FooView extends ViewWithUiHandlers<FooUiHandlers> implements FooPresenter.FooView {    
    public interface Binder extends UiBinder<HTMLPanel, FooView> {
    }

    SomeWidget someWidget;

    @Inject
    public PlayerView(Binder binder, SomeWidget someWidget) {
        initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
        this.someWidget = someWidget;
    }
}
```

Would this work? does anybody know how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done!

Bind your `SomeWidget` class in Singleton:

```java
bind(SomeWidget.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

so both views will have the same `SomeWidget` instance.

If your `SomeWidget` is used in UiBinder (like in `BarView`), you must annotate your `SomeWidget` field with `@UiField(provided = true)`:

```java
@UiField(provided = true)
SomeWidget someWidget;
```

and assign the field in your constructor **before** the call to `initWidget`:

```java
@Inject
public PlayerView(Binder binder, SomeWidget someWidget) {
    this.someWidget = someWidget;
    initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
}
```

You must also do those 2 tricks in `FooView`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! just a follow-up: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gwt-platform/UqkpOmhO3kc